# Kendo ui grid nested model issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have an asp.net mvc application. I have a model like this:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string City{ get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public List<InventoryViewModel> InventoryList { get; set; }
    public string Statu { get; set; }
}
```

InventoryViewModel:

```
public class InventoryViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I have an application form in my project. I am using wizard like structures in order to implement application step by step. One of the steps contain Inventory information only. An application have more than one inventory. To achieve this I am trying to use kendo ui grid component.

My view works with ApplicationViewModel. In inventory step I have this kendo grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<InventoryViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(model => model.ID).Width(25);
        columns.Bound(model => model.Brand).Width(50);
        columns.Bound(model => model.Number).Width(25);
        columns.Bound(model => model.Description).Width(50);
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit();
        }
    ).Title("Inventory").Width(200);
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar =>
    {
        toolbar.Create();
        toolbar.Save();
    })
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(datasource => datasource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ID);
            model.Field(p => p.ID).Editable(false);

        })
        .PageSize(20)
        .Create(create => create.Action("CreateInventory", "Application"))
        .Destroy(destoy => destoy.Action("DeleteInventory", "Application"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("ReadInventory", "Application"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("UpdateInventory", "Application"))
    )
)
```

For create inventory, I have this controller method:

```
public ActionResult CreateInventory([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")] IEnumerable<InventoryViewModel> model)
{
    if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //service.Create(model);
    }

    return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

This code works properly (I am getting inventory information with 'model' parameter). But I need to bind this inventory information to InventoryViewModel inside the ApplicationViewModel. Because after all steps, when I posted my application form, I need application information and inventory list information.

But when I submit my application form, InventoryList that is inside the ApplicationViewModel comes through as null. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you persisting the ApplicationViewModel data on the client?

Comment: My wizard works with javascript. The page isn't posted at wizard steps. I only need to bind inventory list that comes through with kendo grid, to InventoryList that is inside my main model.